# Django : Set is_active flag for User created by social-auth-app-django and google_oauth2

Tags: django, django-forms, social-auth-app-django

I am using social-auth-app-django for signup-signin of new users using google oauth2 authentication.

after signup a new user is created in my db but the is_active is set as false, I want to  set `is_active` as true only for users created by this social_auth google authentication

(for other users who sign up using email-password I activate them by sending an account activation email)
I have tried setting is_active = True for all users with no password , but I feel this way is insecure and hackish .
How do I modify the social_auth_login flow to activate users as well ?
I am using a custom User model :

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
        # else:
        #     user.is_active = True           <-------- tried this , worked too
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('user_type', user_constants.SUPERUSER)
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

..

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None # remove username field, we will use email as unique identifier
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    client_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True,
         default = uuid.uuid4,
         editable = False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=user_constants.USER_TYPE_CHOICES, default=user_constants.CLIENT_ADMIN)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()
```

..

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
  'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
  'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
  'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'register.User'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USER_FIELDS = ['email']
```

..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Django, the boolean `is_active`

> designates whether this user account should be considered active. We
> recommend that you set this flag to False instead of deleting
> accounts; that way, if your applications have any foreign keys to
> users, the foreign keys won’t break.

In your case, I would put `is_active` as True by default (if you want to delete an account, you just put it False).

Following your remark

> (for other users who sign up using email-password I activate them by
> sending an account activation email)

you can add a boolean `is_email_verified` : if the user is created by social auth, it means the `is_email_verified` is True; if the user is created following email-password, `is_email_verified` is False and must be set to True by sending an account activation email.

Thanks to that you can have 4 states with the 2 booleans `is_active` and `is_email_verified` : a user who wants to connect must have both of them as True. It seems secure to me.